# Can I say "From 0 to 10" instead of "On a scale from 0 to 10"?

Tags: vocabulary

I would like to know if it is grammatically correct to say
"**From** 0 to 10" instead of "**On a scale from** 0 to 10"

Comment: Please edit your question to give us the full context. The prepositional phrase, "from 0 to 10" is correct, as in, "*Pick a number **from 0 to 10***." Is that what you want to know?

Comment: scales and numbers are not exactly the same thing. For opinions from people, we generally say on a scale from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, but it all depends on the context. This is fine:

> I'm thinking of a number from 1 to 10.

However, if you're talking about using a rating scale, "On a scale from x to y" is like an idiom. You would almost always include it.

> On a scale from 1 to 10, where 1 is the worst and 10 is the best, please rate the following items.

Also, while mathematicians and computer scientists are very comfortable starting with the number zero, the general population usually likes to start with the number 1 when using *rating scales*.